# JSON Schema different properties must be related

Tags: validation, properties, jsonschema

Let say Im using JSON schema to validate an api spec. So, this is a minimal example of what I have :

```
{
    "title": "spec",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "swagger": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^(1[.]0|2[.]0|3[.]0)$"
        },
        "api-name": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[a-zA-z]+[_][a-zA-z]+$"
        },
        "api-version": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^v[1-9]$"
        },
        "basePath": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^\/[a-zA-Z]{1,30}_[a-zA-Z]{1,30}(_[a-zA-Z]{1,30})?(_[a-zA-Z]{1,30})?(_[a-zA-Z]{1,30})?\/v[1-9]$"
        }
    }
}
```

And this an example of something that would validate as a valid input :

```
{
    "swagger" : "2.0",
    "api-name" : "get_products",
    "api-version" : "v2",
    "basePath" : "/fake_path/v5"

}
```

But I want **basePath** to be tied to the values of **api-name** and **api-version** so something like my input gets rejected. **How can I achieve something like this?**

I am using this for my testings :

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: Specific values or are you saying you want the value of api-version to be part of the value of basePath?

Comment: Exactly, if my api-name is **cars** and the version is **v1**, then the basepath should be **/cars/v1**. @Relequestual

Comment: Nope. Can't do that. Value templating is something that appears in JSON Hyper Schema, but not JSON Schema.

Comment: @Relequestual Thanks for clarifying this :)